# Is there a name for this generalization of derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations, transformation

I know that the derivative of a function $f: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$ at $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$ can be defined to be the linear function $T: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$ satisfying $f(x + h) = f(x) + T(h) + E(h)$ where $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\| E(h) \|}{\| h \|} = 0$.

Obviously, we can modify this definition and require $T$ to possess any property we like. For example, we can require $T$ to be just additive instead of linear or we can require it to be orthogonal in addition to being linear.

Is there a name for this kind of generalization of derivatives and how can I find more information about them?

Comment: If you still approximate your function with linear maps, and just say something like $T$ is orthogonal, then you just have a differential equation. If you require $T$ to be a whole other type of operator then linear, then there are other kinds of approximations (like Taylor series, which work even in multiple variables) studied, but the more obscure you get, the less useful. It would help if you had a concrete example of a problem you want to solve in mind.

Comment: @user951252 What do you mean by a differential equation in the case of orthogonal $T$? I have no concrete problem in my mind, I am just curious. I was studying complex analysis and while studying, I have noticed that complex differentiability is actually equivalent to the differentiability of functions from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$ with $T$ is a composition of scalings and rotations. This made me wonder what happens if we loosen the scaling + rotation condition a little bit to, for example, just orthogonal, which properties of the complex derivative is conserved?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the linear map $T$ is known as the `differential` of $f$, denoted as $\mathrm d f$, not its `derivative` (which is used for functions of a single variable)

Comment: @MetinErsinArıcan Being orthogonal is just some system of equations and so you get a system of differential equations.

Comment: Re: the comment about "loosen the scaling + rotation condition a little bit to, for example, just orthogonal," this is actually more of a _tightening_ (every orthogonal mapping of positive determinant is complex), and the only complex differentiable mappings with orthogonal derivatives are affine, of the form $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z + b$ for some real $\theta$ and complex $b$.